# My usb flash memory is not detected in linux, but is detected in windows

Tags: linux, usb

My removable USB flash memory is not detected in Linux. I test 2 systems: SUSE and Ubuntu. Of course it is listed by `lsusb` command but in `fdisk` or `df` it is not listed. It light on, but not detected. On the other hand it is detected in another Windows 7 PC. There I format it from exfat to ntfs, fat32 but no result in SUSE and Ubuntu. I remember that some time I work to make these USB bootable and have some try to send ISO file to it, maybe it is the cause.
I appreciate any advice.

Comment: Plug it in in Linux, run `sudo fdisk -l` - edit your answer and post the info.

Comment: You could also try: `dmesg -w` then insert the USB stick and see the possible error messages.